# How to dump a postgres DB into a .sql file

Tags: postgresql

I have a "cinema" DB in postgres and I want to dump all its tables and data in a cinema.sql file.

This file will contain all the sql code for re-creating the schema, tables and filling them with the data.

I already have a bank.sql file (for the "bank" DB) which I can execute via PSQL console in pg Admin III and import using the command

```
/i *path to my bank.sql file*
```

Now, I want to produce a cinema.sql file like bank.sql, but I don't know how to do it.

It's not the backup/restore feature of course, because it produces a .backup file.

I've also tried

```
pg dump > cinema.dump
```

In PSQL console but I can't find a .sql file anywhere, so I don't think it is what I'm looking for either.

Couldn't find anything useful for what I need in Postgres documentation unfortunately so I hope you can help me because I'm just a beginner.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try `pg_dump -d cinema_database > cinema.sql` ?

Comment: Well, `pg_dump > cinema.dump` will not create a `.sql` file because you told it to create a `.dump` file. To get a "sql" file simply use `pg_dump > cinema.sql`. Also `pg_dump` is **NOT** a SQL statement. You do not run it from within `psql` you run it from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments and the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html), you should use *pg_dump* command line tool.

`pg_dump cinema > cinema.sql`

Answer (score 1):

I've made it! Don't know if it's the 100% right way to do it, though, but I think it is.

I'll report here just in case someone else might need this in the future and it can be of help.

I selected the db I wanted to dump in .sql file and then right click -> backup.

Here, as format, I chose plain instead of custom, and "mydbdump.sql" as file name.

In Dump Options #1 and Dump Options #2 I checked the checkboxes to include everything I needed (e.g. "include CREATE DATABASE statement").

I compared this newly created .sql dump with the one I already had (using Notepad++) and they look the same (even if, of course, they are from different dbs).